# Selecting values from bounded normal distribution in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have NetLogo draw values from a bounded random normal distribution following the recommendation in a previous question in stackoverflow

[NetLogo : How to make sure a variable stays in a defined range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230685/netlogo-how-to-make-sure-a-variable-stays-in-a-defined-range/20233830#20233830)

Specifically I'm asking the model to create a circular home range that varies in size according to empirical data

```
set homerange patches in-radius ((sqrt (( random-normal-in-bounds [ 54.4 35.8 19 151 ] * 1000000)/ pi))/ 100)

to-report random-normal-in-bounds [mid dev mmin mmax]
  let result random-normal mid dev
  if result < mmin or result > mmax
    [ report random-normal-in-bounds mid dev mmin mmax ]
  report result
end
```

However I keep getting the error that random-normal-in-bounds expected 4 inputs. I'm sure it's something silly I'm doing but it looks like 4 inputs (54.4, 35.8, 19, 151) to me. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might like to read this, about when to use brackets and when to use parentheses in NetLogo: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Help-About-Brackets-td5003911.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is caused by [] you don't need these brackets.

Update:

```
to test
clear-all
let homerange  nobody
let radius sqrt (( random-normal-in-bounds  54.4 35.8 19 151  * 1000000)/ pi) / 100 
crt 1 [
set homerange  patches in-radius radius
]
ask homerange  [set pcolor violet]
end
to-report random-normal-in-bounds [mid dev mmin mmax]
  let result random-normal mid dev
  if result < mmin or result > mmax
    [ report random-normal-in-bounds mid dev mmin mmax ]
  report result
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marzy.  I tried that but I still get the error.  Really weird.

Comment: It was my mistake ! problem was in calling the function random-normal-in-bounds  54.4 35.8 19 151

Comment: The [] in random-normal-in-bounds 54.4 35.8 19 151 was causing the error