# Changing shape of normal distribution by a slider

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am new both to NetLogo (NL) and Stackoverflow. I am working on NL model of opinion formation and I am stuck with following problem (googling or anything else didn't work for me).

First, turtle-own property `turtles-own [opinion]` is defined. Next, there is a random normal distribution of opinion variable (ranges from -1 to 1). I want to be able to account for different shapes of opinion distribution in range from -1 to 1. This is done by using `random-normal` command with two inputs: mean (set to 0) and std. dev. (set by slider); i.e. the shape is given by the std. dev. value.

Here is a code of setup function:

```
to setup
clear-all
random-seed seed
crt number
ask turtles [set opinion random-normal 0 std.dev.]
... (defining other turtles properties)
end
```

Nevertheless, setting std.dev. slider to 1 does not produce expected outcome (bell-shaped distribution), but rather uniform distribution. I am not sure whether this is a conceptual or technical problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal distributions don't have a restricted range, thus I'm not sure you want to use `random-normal`. There are a variety of methods of getting bounded normal-like distributions. See this answer for details: [NetLogo : How to make sure a variable stays in a defined range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230685/netlogo-how-to-make-sure-a-variable-stays-in-a-defined-range/20233830#20233830)

As to why it's not looking bell-shaped, how are you visualizing the resulting distribution? `histogram` can be a little finicky sometimes as you have to explicitly set the x-min, x-max, and bin size. Here's what I get with 10,000 turtles, a standard deviation of 1, x-min = -5, x-max = 5, and interval = 0.1:

[image: Distribution of opinions]

To set the bin size, hit the edit button (looks like a pencil) on the plot pen that's drawing the histogram. Set `interval` on the resulting dialogue to your desired bin size. Let me know if you'd like more detailed instructions for using `histogram`.

Comment: Thank you. I had restricted the x-axis to [-1, 1] interval, so the plot displayed only a part of the normal distribution. Now I am using `ask turtles [set opinion median (list -1 (random-normal 0 std.dev.) 1)]` as suggested in the other thread. This works fine, nevertheless the std. dev. value for bell-shape like distribution is around 0.3.