# Generate random number within a range in NetLogo

Tags: random, netlogo

I am trying to generate random numbers using the `random-poisson` function.  This function only seems to allow me to give it the mean, while this is OK, I also want to give it a `min` and `max` value.   For example, if I wanted to create a function that generates a random week number (1-52), with the most likely pick being, say, week 30, how would I create a function in NetLogo that creates a random number that doesn't exceed 52?

Comment: You might want to look at this answer dealing with a normal distribution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20233830/2215706

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetLogo : How to make sure a variable stays in a defined range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230685/netlogo-how-to-make-sure-a-variable-stays-in-a-defined-range)